# Checking graph properties in linear time given only the adjacency matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph, adjacency-matrix

I came across a problem concerning graphs. 
Let's define a rake graph.

> A n-vertex graph is a *rake* when it meets certain conditions:
>
> 1. there is a vertex of degree 1 in the graph
> 2. this vertex is connected to a vertex of degree 2
> 3. this second vertex is connected to another vertex of degree n-2 other vertices may or may not be connected to each other.

I have been given an adjacency matrix for a graph of n vertices. My task is to check if the graph represented by the given matrix is a "rake" or not. The catch is that is has to be done in linear time.

I've tried like everything. It's easy to do when you have adjacency list, but how do I make it take  O(n) time with the matrix given?

Comment: Simply scan adjacencies accumulating counts for each node as you go using a hashtable to hold the counters for each node.  Then check the nodes to see if there is one of adjacency 1,2, and n-2.  That's O(n).

Comment: @RBarryYoung could you say a bit more? I think this problem is not trivial (at least for my skill set).

Comment: just to be 100% clear about `O(n)` for the worst-case? (btw. it is really nice problem;-) thanks for that! )

Comment: well, this problem is said to have a linear solution in all the cases. The only hint I have is that "from the point of being a rake, the vast majority of vertices is not important" - obviously meaning the last vertices coming from the centre

Comment: :-) it is not important but still they are there!

Comment: It's linear in the number of *adjacencies*, not necessarily in the number of nodes.  Since you have to scan the adjacency list (`a`) at least once, it cannot be smaller than that.  And since `a` could be as large as `n*(n-1)/2`, you cannot make it linear in the number of vertexes (`v`).

Comment: @RBarryYoung if edges are represented as *adjacency lists* the problem can be easily solved in `O(n)` (with respect to number of nodes). But in the question the graph is represented as *adjacency matrix* and it makes quite huge difference to perform the search in linear time.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak No, it would be `O(n)` *with respect to the adjacencies*, not wrt the number of nodes.  And even if it's an adjacency *matrix*, technically it's still `O(n)` because it would still be *linear with respect to the input size*.  Making it linear wrt to the number of nodes in either case is impossible, because you have to read each input at least once and that's `O(a) = O(v^2)`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung why?? I have a solution that does not read each input and I am pretty sure that it works in `O(n)` wrt **number of nodes**. **Hint** we can easily verify if given node is of degree bigger than 3 in constant time.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak In the worst case, your solution *does* read each adjacency, and is thus `O(v^2)`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung if you can read bit more carefully: *very initial sketch*, I did not state anywhere it is final version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I seem to have found an answer! There indeed is a linear time algorithm solving this problem, because the problem I presented is called in the world of science checking if a graph is a scorpion graph!

Here you can find the algorithm I'd been looking for.
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs681/2007fa/Handouts/scorpion.pdf

Thanks for help!

Comment: To be more in line with [so] guidelines, you should consider extracting sufficient information from the link and putting it in the answer such that the algorithm can be understood without having to check the link.

Comment: +1, for me it was the best problem I encounter in SO so far -- just could not stop thinking about it :-) I really believed it is doable in linear time. Just regret a little bit that you post the answer so soon;-) [I just could not resist to check what it is]

Comment: Well, I'm glad you liked it, pozdrowienia z Gdańska :)